# Array will not pass through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, object

I've creating an array and trying to pass it to a PHP file through an ajax function, along with other variables. The other variables send fine, but the workout array doesn't send.

```
workout = [];
$('.workout > section').each(function (i) {

    var self = $(this),
        exerciseid = self.attr('id'),
        id = i;

    workout[id] = []; // key: exercise id
    self.find('.exercise > li').each(function(i) {

        var self = $(this);

        if(!self.hasClass('newitem')) {

            workout[id][i] = []; // key: set
            workout[id][i]['exerciseid'] = exerciseid;

            self.find('input').each(function() {

                var self = $(this),
                    value = self.val(),
                    role = self.attr('data-type');

                workout[id][i][role] = value;

            });
        };

    });

});
```

[Fiddle of the created array](http://jsfiddle.net/kMv3H/11/). I believe the problem is here.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/lib/track.php",
    data: {
        'token' : token,
        'date' : date,
        'diet' : diet,
        'workout' : workout,
    }
})
```

Am I missing something? This is the current state of the outputted $_POST array:

```
Array
(
    [token] => 12E7AS13FEA52B9AEF4074CC8A5E8841C5AA087VA
    [date] => 2014-01-13
    [diet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [meal] => 2
                    [foodid] => 4043
                    [unit] => 3
                    [altgrams] =>  
                    [altname] =>  
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )    
)
```

Comment: Did you check that your JS function (each) are called ? You can use console.log("a log") to debug it.

Comment: Yes. If you see the console of the fiddle, the array is being created. I'm stumped why it's not being passed through the ajax.

Comment: Yes, the array is alright, maybe you should debug it before the AJAX request.

Comment: Have you tried `workout[id][i] = {}` (instead of `... = []`)? Typically when an array is serialised only the actual elements are included, that is, properties with numeric indexes, not properties with non-numeric string keys. Using an object (`{}`) it should serialise correctly.

Answer (score 1):

updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMv3H/13/) above:

```
...
workout[id][i] = **{}**; // key: set
....
```

this is not an array but an object with properties. In PHP this will be an associative array, but this concept is unknown in javascript.